# Viewport only shows part of the scaled cube

Tags: objects, 3d-view

[image: Blender 2.79b]

I created a cube and scaled it to dimension 1m x 1m. I can't see the entire cube and only see part of cube. Can anybody help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Viewport hit *"N"* to show the *Properties panel*.

Then, under *"View"*, change the clipping *"End"* value to fit your cube.

(Note: 1km is the default value.)

[image: Properties Panel]

Comment: Hi. Nice answer. Might be an idea to scale down any screenshots in future as they're quite large at the minute.

Comment: Changed it ^^ Thanks for the advice, wouldn't have noticed it myself.